# How start akka cluster sharding?

Tags: scala, akka, sharding, akka-cluster

To start akka cluster sharding I should call `ClusterSharding(system).start` with some parameters. Should I start cluster sharding for all node manually? I mean is it enough to call `ClusterSharding(system).start` from one node at start up or all node should call this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to call it on each node that wants to participate in the cluster sharding.

From http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3-M2/contrib/cluster-sharding.html

"When using the sharding extension you are first, typically at system startup on each node in the cluster, supposed to register the supported entry types with the ClusterSharding.start method"